# Pass a List<Object> from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and I need some help passing a List from a view to a controller.
I already have the List in my controller I sent it to the view and I want to send it back.

here is my controller first:

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
...
return View("ImportPreview", items);
}
```

and here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Item>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Import Preview";
}
<h2>Import Preview</h2>
<h3>Imported Items</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ImportToDB", "ImportItems"))
{
<table id="tableItems" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Item Ref</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th>Item Notes</th>
        <th>Available Qty</th>
        <th>Category Ref</th>
        <th>Time Stamp</th>
        <th>Is Trackable by Variation</th>
    </tr>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.AccountID);
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemRef)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemNotes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AvailableQty)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemCategoryRef)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.recordTimeStamp)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsTrackableByVariation)
        </td>
    </tr>
   }
   </table>

     <input type="submit" name="Import" id="Import" value="Import" />
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

finally here is my last part in the controller where I have to collect the List<>:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImportToDB(List<Item> items)
{
...
}
```

the problem is that always items is null here in the controller.

Can someone tell me where is my mistake.
Thank you in advance :)

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: display for doesn't tie the data to the model.  Only the other for helpers will do that.  Passing a list isn't easy.  I have only been able to do it by dynamically building the list in jquery and passing it through an ajax call.  if you are wanting them to edit table rows I would recommend saving the rows individually as they are changed

Comment: Thanks @MattBodily for this comment. I tried out the Html.HiddenFor and the Html.EditorFor and always I face the same problem. I don't need to edit anything, I just need to display the result to get an approval from the end user before inserting them to the DB. if there is another way to get the List<Item> it may helps.

Comment: If you don't need the data from the list then I wouldn't try to send it back to the controller.  Send back whatever fields you need and just regenerate the list on the controller side.